# Reducing background image opacity in one div

Tags: css, image, background, opacity

I need to control background image opacity. I tried to use Opacity option, but it effects all header elements.
Can I reduce opacity of background image in this code?

```
.header-container { 
    width: 100%; 
    background: url(/images/header-bg6.png) repeat;
    display: block;
```

Comment: can we have some more code html/css, structure needed and what is suppose to be seen through ? options could be avalaible (pseudo, background-blend-mode, inset box-shadow , ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want this then you have to change the image to PNG width transparent image

**or**

You can take a `div` which have `position: absolute`; before the `header-container` which will have the same height as `header-container`, then apply the `background-image` and `opacity: 0.2; filter: alpha(opacity=20);`

I hope I will helps you.